# Get parameter values from batches in PreparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc

I have an application where preparedStatement.addBatch() is used heavily. 
So a lot of:

```
preparedStatement.setLong(1,1L);
preparedStatement.setString(2,"XXX");
preparedStatement.setInt(3,33);
...
preparedStatement.addBatch();
```

inside loops is going on.
Now I need to read the parameters that are already passed to each single batch.
Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you think you *need* to read those parameters?

Comment: If you're setting the parameters, surely you can just read what you set? What problem are you facing here that you're trying to solve this way?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. `PreparedStatement` has no API to get values back from the statement. If you want to be able to do this, you will need to keep track of this yourself.

Personally, I think having such a requirement is rather odd, and I can't think of a situation where you would need to be able to do this.